# How to move projects between workspaces in Asana

Tags: project-management, asana

How should I move a project from a workplace to another (for example my Personal Projects)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've written a (very basic) front-end to [AWeg's version of the copy script](https://gist.github.com/AWeg/5814427).

You can use it here: http://asana.kothar.net

It works for small projects, but at the moment I don't have any large ones to test it with - I suspect it will time out on the server, since it tries to do everything in one go.

Sourcecode [is available](https://bitbucket.org/mikehouston/organiseasana) of course.

[image: Screenshot of the Asana Project Organiser]

Comment: I've just used this (on a small project) and it seems to have worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you simply can't!

Quote from Asana ([source](https://asana.com/guide/workspaces/basics)):

> Workspaces are self-contained: projects and tasks cannot move between
>   Workspaces or be moved into Organization.

I had to create the projects from scratch in the new workspace - but was obviously unable to preserve the projects trail of comments from the initial workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can move projects between workspaces with some work. This is not my solution and original credit goes to [MhdHejazi](https://github.com/MhdHejazi)

With some testing, it seems that Aweg's fork here works: https://gist.github.com/AWeg/5814427

You'll need to be comfortable with PHP and have your own hosting account. I was able to easily transfer projects from one workspace to another. You'll also need your API key as well.

Comment: It should be noted that this won't actually move/copy a project, but rather copy tasks from one project to the other. So if you want to move a project, you'll have to create the other project first.
Nonetheless - huge time saver for big projects with a lot of tasks.