# How to combine workspaces in Asana?

Tags: asana

When my company started using Asana, more than one team opened a workspace.
**How can we combine the various workspaces to one?**

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to copy projects from one workspace to another one at a time using [this script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50025/2924)

Possible Caveats:

- The script seems unverified on large projects as of yet
- It's probably more work than an asana supported combining
- There may be other metadata in the workspace that won't transfer

Comment: But then you miss out on tasks not assigned under projects.